# The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory in Ubuntu

Tags: android, angular2-nativescript

I placed Android SDK inside **/opt/android-sdk** and also updated **.bashrc** file with the lines :

> export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
>   export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH

then I reloaded the **.bashrc** file:

`source ~/.bashrc`

After that I checked the **ANDROID_HOME** by hitting the command as:

`echo $ANDROID_HOME`

which resulted as:

`/opt/android-sdk`

which is the correct location where I placed it. After that I created a *NativeScript Mobile Application* project :

`tns create MobileApp --ng`

then I entered inside the *MobileApp* directory and tried to add platform as Android:

`tns platform add android`

but I got this error which stated as follow :

> The **ANDROID_HOME** environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.

Did I miss anything in the above process of adding Android as platform in *NativeScript Mobile Application* project?

Comment: Try logging out of Ubuntu and logging back in, to make sure all your user processes have the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable. Perhaps `tns` works with some previously-forked daemon process.

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. Anyway thanks for response.

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1097) might help you I guess.

Comment: Pro-tip: console I/O is best presented in questions/answers here using code Markdown rather than quote blocks. Use a four-space prefix or select the text and click the 'code' button.

Answer (score 9):

## Issue solved :

I added *ANDROID_HOME* and *PATH* in **.profile** file in **$HOME** directory as :

> export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
>   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

then I restarted the system and tried with below command :

`tns platform add android`

and then it worked. Here's the logs for reference.

`Copying template files...`
`◠ Installing tns-androidbabel-traverse@6.21.0 node_modules/babel-traverse`
`├── babel-messages@6.8.0`
`├── globals@9.14.0`
`├── babylon@6.14.1`
`├── lodash@4.17.3`
`├── debug@2.5.2 (ms@0.7.2)`
`├── invariant@2.2.2 (loose-envify@1.3.0)`
`├── babel-types@6.21.0 (to-fast-properties@1.0.2, esutils@2.0.2)`
`├── babel-code-frame@6.20.0 (js-tokens@2.0.0, esutils@2.0.2, chalk@1.1.3)`
`└── babel-runtime@6.20.0 (regenerator-runtime@0.10.1, core-js@2.4.1)`
`◝ Installing tns-androidbabel-types@6.21.0 node_modules/babel-types`
`├── to-fast-properties@1.0.2`
`├── esutils@2.0.2`
`├── lodash@4.17.3`
`└── babel-runtime@6.20.0 (regenerator-runtime@0.10.1, core-js@2.4.1)`
`◝ Installing tns-androidbabylon@6.14.1 node_modules/babylon`
`◝ Installing tns-androidlazy@1.0.11 node_modules/lazy`
`Project successfully created.`

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect solution here, you may face other problems too. I've provided the solutions for other as well.

setting up the NS (native script).
 tns doctor android home issue.unable to run this command.

- Changed the environment variable to
- set ANDROID_HOME=C:\ installation location \android-sdk
- set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
- Close cmd or VS, and restarted it, ran it again
- Done.

Unable to craete the basic project from tns create. (there was an issue with JSON string)

- Delete all the files from this location.
- C:\Users\binu\AppData\Roaming\npm and
- C:\Users\binu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
- Then update your npm to the latest version by running npm i
  npm@latest -g
     npm i -g nativescript
- [Done]

Need to create android emulator to run the test, one of the method is avd manager.

- cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
- sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
- avdmanager create avd -n test -k
  "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
- and then run "tns run android"
- but now if it shows black screen.
- sdkmanager emulator
- [done]